# Share PowerBI report securely with members outside org with a premium per user license

Tags: powerbi, share

Hi I have a powerbi premium per user license and want to share my report with users outside my organization in a secure manner (not publish for public access) without them having to pay anything additional to get a license. Is that possible?

I have tried adding the email id to "share with specific people" and it asks me to create a guest user in azure active directory. When I share with a user within the org with no license it takes the person to a 60 day free trial period- so it does not seem free even for internal people in the org strangely. I thought of using the powerbi app to publish and share (hoping that might be free access) but I do not see that option with my license either.

Answer (score 0):

Reports published to a workspace using Premium Per User can only be accessed by users with a Premium Per User license.

Reports published to a Pro workspace can only be accessed by users with a Pro or Premium Per User license.

> to share my report with users outside my organization in a secure manner

You must either assign licenses to their guest users, or they can have the license in their home tenant, or you can host the report in a Premium Capacity workspace.  Purchasing a Premium Capacity is required to share reports with unlicensed or Free Licensed users.

Comment: For completeness - [embedding for customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app) also could be an option.

Comment: Yes.  That still requires purchasing a capacity, but it can be a very small Azure A-SKU or F-SKU.